# Is there a MIME type for C64 .PRG files?

Tags: commodore-64, emulation

I'm writing an emulator with an HTTP API that could usefully accept C64 .PRG files as the request body of a POST request. This means it has to be able to detect such files by their MIME type: POST requests don't come with a file name (just a request body and the body's MIME type), so there no extension that the server can check, and the .PRG format is really not amenable to auto-detection.

I will make up a new `vnd` MIME type if necessary, but I'd rather use an existing one if there is one - however I had difficulty finding anything via Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official recognized mime type but there are already some other applications using the standard way of defining private types as `application/x-*`. For example

`application/x-c64-cartridge` for C64 Cartridge files (`.CRT`)

`application/x-c64-program`  for C64 program files (`.PRG`)

`application/x-c64-datadisk`for C64 floppy (data only/single side) (`.D64`)

`application/x-c64-rawdisk` C64 Floppy Disk(raw/single side) (`.G64`)

`application/x-c64-snapshot` for C64 Snapshot files (`.S64`)

`audio/x-sid` for SID audio files (`.SID`)

**If you realy want to define something of your own** you must stay with the well defined way of mime type generation, as defined by RFC 2045/46. This application falls for sure within the reserved top media type of `application`, as this is a binary and application specific format. [See RFC2046 Section 3 Type 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046). The subtype then should follow the rules of an `x-token` as described in [Section 5.1 of RFC2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045).

---

*A quick search did show some other Commodore related types* like `application/d64`, `application/x-d64`,`application/x-cbm-d64`, `application/t64`, `application/x-t64`, `application/x-cbm-t64` but they seem somewhat less desirable. Then again, there are maybe thousands of C64 freaks out there creating their own definitions :))

Comment: Thanks. Which applications support this? (Also note that [`x-` is deprecated](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648) and [types with the `x-` prefix are no longer part of the unregistered tree](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6838#section-3.4)!)

Comment: After figuring out the right Google search syntax: http://www.c64emulator.111mb.de/index.php?site=pp_plugin&lang=en&group=c64 mentions `application/x-c64-program`. Good enough for me, and I'll just put up with the `x-` prefix.

Comment: RFC6838 is 'just' a best practice recomendation, **not** a standard like 2045/46. Ofc, you're always free to go thru the IANA registration procedure to make up a new standard type. Personally I'd rather spend the time with the project and use established standards. the way they are made.

Comment: `cbm` makes much more sense than `c64`: a PRG is a capture of a file, not a piece of media, and Commodore used the same layout for files across its 8-bit line. PET software is often found as PRGs. Vic-20 software is often found as PRGs (confusingly including cartridges, which tend to have been captured by saving as a file). C16+4 software is often found as PRGs. Etc. Ditto D64 and G64 are floppy images which may contain software for any Commodore GCR platform. Nothing about most of those files strictly implies the C64. If research suggests MIME types still aren't codified, I'd avoid `c64`.

Comment: @Tommy Yes, there might be many reasons to use different identifyers. And using a certain machien name for generic formats sounds wrong. But it might be good to remember that mime-types don't need to make sense. their primary reason is to act as **unique** identifyier for a specific data format. Therefore it might be wise to use an existing identifiyer to improve compatibility, instead of inventing another one out of dogmatic reason and increase incompatibility. Don't you think so?

Comment: @Raffzahn hence "If research suggests MIME types still aren't codified...". So, yes, you're agreeing with me.

Comment: @Tommy From all of my heart, yes,I do. Just logic tells me that it's better to yuse a crapy ID because it is already in use by others than inventing a better one. Compatibility is what we want. Invisible beauty comes second (or even less) :(

Comment: @Raffzahn sorry, I'm obviously expressing myself poorly. Alas, not for the first time. That final sentence is meant to say: if going out and looking suggests that the question isn't actually settled — if there are enough instances of `application/x-cbm-prg` or whatever that anything `c64` isn't standard enough that doing so would affect compatibility — then I'd tend away from `c64` for failing correctly to describe the thing being transmitted and thereby failing the only purpose of a MIME type. Impliedly: if the matter is already settled, then so be it. The provincials have won.

Comment: @Tommy Oh, I think I got it already first time. Maybe I should rephrase my point as a sequence of steps. Identifiers are arbitary and can be any sequence of letters as long as they are unique. If there is none arround, I'd define a good one. But as soon as there is a single application using an existing identifier for my data, no matter how stupid named, I'll accept it. Now I'd only go ahead and check if there are maybe others and if yes, which one _seams_ to have a promising followship. I will always put compatibility over my need for a nice identifier - even above a better data format.

Comment: @Raffzahn speaking as one of those that has at any time implemented support for TZX, I agree but hate myself for doing so.